# Create a column in pandas dataframe by splitting the values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['AA_L8_ZZ', 'AA_L8_YY', 'AA_L80_XX', 'AA_L8_CC'], 'col2':['AAA_L8_1D', 'AA_L8_2D', 'AA_L80_5C', 'AA_L8_6Y']})
df

    col1        col2
0   AA_L8_ZZ    AAA_L8_1D
1   AA_L8_YY    AA_L8_2D
2   AA_L80_XX   AA_L80_5C
3   AA_L8_CC    AA_L8_6Y
```

I want to create a column as col3

col3 = (first 2 instances of 'col1' after splitting by _ ) + _ + (3rd instance of 'col2' after splitting it by _)

My expected output:

```
    col1        col2        col3
0   AA_L8_ZZ    AAA_L8_1D   AA_L8_1D
1   AA_L8_YY    AA_L8_2D    AA_L8_2D
2   AA_L80_XX   AA_L80_5C   AA_L80_5C
3   AA_L8_CC    AA_L8_6Y    AA_L8_6Y
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try some regex:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].str.extract('^(.*_.*_)').add(df['col2'].str.extract('^.*_.*_([^_]*)'))[0]
```

Output:

```
        col1       col2       col3
0   AA_L8_ZZ  AAA_L8_1D   AA_L8_1D
1   AA_L8_YY   AA_L8_2D   AA_L8_2D
2  AA_L80_XX  AA_L80_5C  AA_L80_5C
3   AA_L8_CC   AA_L8_6Y   AA_L8_6Y
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use str accessor methods like this:

```
df['col3'] = (df['col1'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[0]
                        .str.cat(df['col2'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[-1], 
                                 sep='_'))
df
```

Output:

```
        col1       col2       col3
0   AA_L8_ZZ  AAA_L8_1D   AA_L8_1D
1   AA_L8_YY   AA_L8_2D   AA_L8_2D
2  AA_L80_XX  AA_L80_5C  AA_L80_5C
3   AA_L8_CC   AA_L8_6Y   AA_L8_6Y
```

Where `rsplit` does split starting at the end(right) and `n` parameter is to limit how many times to split.  `.str[n]` is the index of the list generated from the split, and `cat` is concatenating strings together with `sep='_'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['AA_L8_ZZ', 'AA_L8_YY', 'AA_L80_XX', 'AA_L8_CC'], 'col2':['AAA_L8_1D', 'AA_L8_2D', 'AA_L80_5C', 'AA_L8_6Y']})

#defining a list to store the contents for col3
a = []

#extracting the values by first changing the elements of both columns into string and then joining the extracted values and inserting into the list 
for i,j in zip(df.col1, df.col2):
    a.append(str(i).split('_')[0]+"_"+str(i).split('_')[1]+"_"+str(j).split('_')[2])

#defining new column and assigning the value to it
df['col3'] =  a

print(df)
```